# Analytic map from punctured half plane to annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an old comp question.

Consider the punctured upper half plane $U$ and the annuals $A$ given by
 $U:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\backslash{\{i\}}\}$ and $A:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2\}.$

Show that there is an analytic function $f:U\rightarrow A$ such that $f(U)=A$ and then explain why $f$ could not be injective.

My idea is to use a branch of $f(z)=z^{\alpha i}$ for some appropriate choice of $\alpha$.
Flying low to the ground and using definitions $z^{\alpha i}=e^{-\alpha Argz}(\cos(\alpha \log|z|)+i\sin(\alpha\log|z|))$, so that $1<e^{-\alpha Argz}<2$. This gets a bit messy and taking $Argz\in(0,\pi)$ I was wishfully thinking that $\alpha=\frac{-1}{\pi}\log2$ would work.

Then showing that $f$ is surjective is also a mess. The part about not being injective I understand.

If someone has a better method for this problem I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: For your definition of $U$, do you intend to have $\operatorname{Im}z > 0$ instead of $\operatorname{Im} z < 0$?

Comment: Yes, I'll correct that.

Comment: Can you map the upper half-plane biholomorphically to a strip, say $0 < \operatorname{Re} z < \log 2$?

Comment: Using $f(z)=\frac{\log(2)\log(z)}{\pi}$ would map to $0<Im(z)<\log(2)$ then $g(z)=-iz$ would map to the desired strip. I'll think about how to apply this.

Comment: Oh and then hit it with $e^z$, I think I got it.

Comment: Right. And since $e^z$ has period $2\pi i$, the non-injectivity as well as the surjectivity are easy to show.

Comment: Great. Do you want to post as an answer? If not I can do it in case someone else finds it useful in the future.